# Error in code for Leetcode 113: Third Max Number; code gives wrong output dont know why

Tags: c++, set

```
class Solution {
public:
    int thirdMax(vector<int>& nums) {
        int n = nums.size();
        set<int, greater<int> > s;
        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
            s.insert(nums[i]);
        }
        n=s.size();
        set<int, greater<int> >::iterator iter = s.begin();
        if(n<3){
            advance(iter, n-1);
            return *iter;
        }else{
            advance(iter, n-3);
            return *iter;
        }
    }
};
```

This is my code for the problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/third-maximum-number/

Pls help as to why the output for this testcase is wrong.

```
Input: 2, 3, 1
Expected Output: 1
Code Output: 3
```

Comment: You have the input that produces the wrong output. That should make it very easy to debug by stepping through the code in a debugger for the specified input.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Using [std::nth_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) makes this a 2-line solution.  Look at the example at the bottom of that page.